# jQuery - adding custom css class if submitted form is blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add custom css class to an icon class (Font Awesome)
when submitted login form contains blank value.

My purpose is to change the icon color to red to indicate the failed login attempt.

The following is my jQuery code but it doesn't seem to add my custom css class `fail`
to an icon class `fa-user`.

```
$('#form_1').submit(function () {

    var username = $.trim($('#username_1').val());
    var password = $.trim($('#password_1').val());

    if ( username == '' || password == '' ) {
        $('.fa-user').addClass('fail');
        return false;
    }

});
```

Here is my [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sungsoonz/CgLKa/2/)

Comment: I am sorry but I don't get the down voters. I admit that I forgot to include the jquery library in the fiddle but not in my working files. The solution I have so far still doesn't work without `novalidate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#signIn_1').on ("click", function () {    
    var username = $.trim($('#username_1').val());
    var password = $.trim($('#password_1').val());

    if ( username == '' || password == '' )
    {
        $('.fa-user').addClass('fail');
        return false;
    }
});
```

That way your form is checked BEFORE it is submitted (i.e. before it is checked by the browser itself).

Comment: Thanks. This is a decent solution without disabling html5 validation. Would it be possible though to see both browser and my custom validation at the same time?

Comment: Sure, just don't return false (i.e. let it submit the form anyway). I wouldn't recommend that though for there are browsers that ignore automatic form validation. If you wanted to return false just in browsers that do not support automatic form validation, you would have to manually check what browser is being used.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't include the jQuery library in the fiddle

Demo: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/WueMM/)

Also disable the html5 validation using

```
<form id="form_1" novalidate>
```

Comment: ah. I forgot to include jquery in the fiddle but my working file has it for sure. Is there any way I can get it working without disabling html5 validation?